# WebView и открытие сторонних ссылок

Tags: webview, android-webview

Вот код моего APK, как сделать чтобы ссылки которые не содержат *google.com* открывались в стороннем браузере?

Класс MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("ОШИБКА!");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Нет соединения. Проверьте подключение и повторите попытку.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Повторить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            }

        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");


    }

    //Кнопка выхода

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            backToast.cancel();
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }else{
            backToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Нажмите еще раз для выхода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            backToast.show();
        }
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Картинка для более точного понятия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

- Надо создать дополнительный класс `MyWebViewClient`:

```
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String google = "google.com";
            String google_buf = google.toUpperCase();
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            String url_buf = url.toUpperCase();
            if(google.contains(url_buf)){
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
            } else {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);
                 return true;
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("ОШИБКА!");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Нет соединения. Проверьте подключение и повторите попытку.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Повторить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            }
        }
```

- И применить его к `WebView` с помощью кода:

```
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

P.S. Будет вызываться сторонний браузер если `url` не содержит `google.com`